# Can I use complex HTML with Twitter Bootstrap's Tooltip?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip

If I check [official documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips), I can see a property called HTML:

```
Name    |    Type       |    default  |    Description
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
html    |    boolean    |    false    |    Insert html into the tooltip. 
                                           If false, jquery's text method 
                                           will be used to insert content 
                                           into the dom. Use text if you're 
                                           worried about XSS attacks.
```

It says, "insert html into the tooltip", but the type is boolean. How can I use complex html inside a Tooltip?

Answer (score 281, accepted):

This parameter is just about whether you are going to use complex html into the tooltip. Set it to `true` and then hit the html into the `title` attribute of the tag.

See this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/44khF/200/) - I've set the html attribute to true through the `data-html="true"` in the `<a>` tag and then just added in the html ad hoc as an example.

Comment: Well their documentation isn't so clear on that area. Thanks for sharing this answer! :)

Comment: The bootstrap documentation is notoriously rubbish :) Glad I could clear things up!

Comment: The fiddle example doesn't work for me. I still see the raw HTML code.

Comment: Your quite right - for some reason it doesn't seem to be working anymore :/ I'm really snowed under with work at the moment - but I'll try and look into it this week and update it - bootstrap's has upgraded to 2.3.0 since I wrote this so their might have been changes!

Comment: Despite not changing it the fiddle appears to work again. Odd one - perhaps a fiddle error rather than my code error??

Comment: There's nothing in the changelog about it - but also could be due to bootstrap having the 2.3.1 update?

Comment: Probably some change to Bootstrap code like you suspect. Before I had all my tooltips wired for html titles using {html: true} in the function attributes, but going from 2.2.2 > 2.3.1, I had to add data-html="true" to my elements and just scrapped the {html: true} part. I really wish they would try to get things right more often the first time and not inflict breaking changes constantly between releases.

Comment: I think the reason it doesn't work is jsFiddler doesn't like external files coming from github...or non CDN's

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/44khF/148/.  Also, it only seems to work with the the data attribute and not using html: true in the initialisation if delegates are used.

Answer (score 45):

Another solution to avoid inserting html into *data-title* is to create independant div with tooltip html content, and refer to this div when creating your tooltip :

```
<!-- Tooltip link -->
<p><span class="tip" data-tip="my-tip">Hello world</span></p>

<!-- Tooltip content -->
<div id="my-tip" class="tip-content hidden">
    <h2>Tip title</h2>
    <p>This is my tip content</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Tooltips
        $('.tip').each(function () {
            $(this).tooltip(
            {
                html: true,
                title: $('#' + $(this).data('tip')).html()
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This way you can create complex readable html content, and activate as many tooltips as you want.

live demo [here on codepen](http://codepen.io/migli/pen/jWaGJq)

Comment: Fantastic. I'm so glad someone proposed a solution that isn't cramming HTML directly into the data property.

Comment: Works well in Bootstrap 4.5. Weird that this isn't documented anywhere.

Answer (score 37):

Just as normal, using `data-original-title`:

Html:

```
<div rel='tooltip' data-original-title='<h1>big tooltip</h1>'>Visible text</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip({html:true});
```

The html parameter specifies how the tooltip text should be turned into DOM elements. By default Html code is escaped in tooltips to prevent XSS attacks. Say you display a username on your site and you show a small bio in a tooltip. If the html code isn't escaped and the user can edit the bio themselves they could inject malicious code.

Comment: `data-original-title` is where bootstrap temporarily store `title` if it is present. `data-title` is enough if you not have a title, like a `<a href="#" title="xxx">`

Comment: Hello @MattZeunert I have used it and running perfectly fine but I want to update the title as per my coming data without reloading the page and set dynamically, I mean changing the content inside the title.

Answer (score 30):

The `html` data attribute does exactly what it says it does in the docs. Try this little example, no JavaScript necessary (broken into lines for clarification):

```js
<span rel="tooltip" 
     data-toggle="tooltip" 
     data-html="true" 
     data-title="<table><tr><td style='color:red;'>complex</td><td>HTML</td></tr></table>"
>
hover over me to see HTML
</span>
```

JSFiddle demos:

- [**Bootstrap 2.x**](http://jsfiddle.net/2KLuT/)
- [**Bootstrap 3.x**](http://jsfiddle.net/56arN/)

Answer (score 8):

set "html" option to true if you want to have html into tooltip. Actual html is determined by option "title" (link's title attribute shouldn't be set)

```
$('#example1').tooltip({placement: 'bottom', title: '<p class="testtooltip">par</p>', html: true});
```

[Live sample](http://jsfiddle.net/sjsMF/49/)

Answer (score 1):

For bootstrap 5, you can use `data-bs-html="true"` with the title tag `data-bs-original-title="Tooltip Title"`

Answer (score 0):

As of bootstrap 5, you can just specify the contents of the tooltip to be `html` DOM nodes when configuring it. Sample config...

```
// setup tools tips trigger
const tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
const tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
     return new Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl, {
           html: true // <- this should do the trick!
     })
});
```

Comment: I really want to use this method, but I don't understand at all what you're saying. Can you provide the example HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in tooltips with escaped characters in the text, resolved it by using a custom attribute for text content and escaping characters before enabling the tooltip:

**In JSP/HTML**

```
<a id="myTooltip" href="#"
    class="country-list-trigger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-alternative-title="Text with "escaped characters" ==> this should be displayed ==>  "as it is""
    data-html="true" title=""> 
        <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2"></i>
</a>
```

**In Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    enableAllTooltips();
} );

// enable tooltip after getting the title from the custom attribute (does not work when using the default attribute: data-original-title)
function enableAllTooltips() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
      template: '<div class="tooltip tooltip-custom"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>',
      title: function() {
        return escapeHtml(this.getAttribute('data-alternative-title'));
      }
  })
}


// Custom method for replacing escaped characters by there character entities 
function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
    return unsafe
         .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
         .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
         .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
         .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
         .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}
```