# How to assign html value to variable using jstl c:set?

Tags: java, html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, jstl

Hopefully the intention isn't overly skewed...

I'm trying to set a variable with some html value using jstl, and afterwards display it in a bootstrap tooltip. The html is static and quite short, so I don't want to bother about sending the value to jsp as an attribute from any Servlet. So basically it looks as follows;

```
<c:set var="passMsg" value="myHtmlString"/>
<div class="form-group">
    <input data-rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="${passMsg}" data-placement="top" class="form-control" name="password" type="password"/>
</div>
```

I've tried this (*haha! not so intuitive, but hey! it was a cheap shot*);

```
<c:set var="passMsg" value="<p>Passwords must contain <br>at least One Uppercase character <br>& One digit.</p>"/>
```

...and tried body content for the `<c:set/>` tag;

```
<c:set var="passMsg">
    <p>Passwords must contain <br>at least One Uppercase character <br>& One digit.</p>
</c:set>
```

...and to leverage upon XML-escaping capability of the `<c:out/>` tag, I also tried this;

```
<c:set var="passMsg">
    <c:out value="<p>Passwords must contain <br>at least One Uppercase character <br>& One digit.</p>"/>
</c:set>
```

Unfortunately, my tooltip keeps showing the string with tags included as this;

> <p>Passwords must contain <br>at least One Uppercase character <br>& One digit.</p>

whereas what I want is for it to look like this;

> Passwords must contain 
> at least One Uppercase character 
> & One digit.

Comment: This should give you what you want I believe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704789/can-i-use-complex-html-with-twitter-bootstraps-tooltip

Comment: @Simon Thanks for the link.. upvote for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable html mode for the tooltip:

```
data-html="true"
```

See [the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-options)

Comment: Thanks for the tip and +1 for the documentation reference. However I tried this and still didn't get the desired result. Any ideas why though?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/44khF/200/: it works. Try doing it with static HTML in the tooltip, the try doing it with dynamic HTML. Check the generated HTML code to see if it's similar to the static code.

Comment: Ok got it working... turns out I didn't add the javascript for triggering the tooltip like `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()`... I kinda forgot that Bootstrap documentation says "For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in, meaning you must initialize them yourself"... I'm marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: For a bit of knowledge seeking though, @JBNizet, do you know why the default tooltip was showing (and it was not rendering the html properly) even though I hadn't initially added the javascript that should trigger it?

Comment: It probably was not shown. What you saw was a standard, unstyled native title, created by the browser and not by bootstrap.