# How to make a word bold in a text mentioned in bootstrap tooltip CSS/Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to show a bootstrap tooltip on hover over an image. I have a text in that tooltip that i need to make it bold.

I tried this from the mentioned source, but didnt work form me..

```
  <button class="infoTipsBox" type ="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"data-original-title='<b>big tooltip</b>'>      
  </button>
```

Js:

```
$(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
```

What im i doing wrong??
In the above text in the `title` attribute, I am trying to make the "bootstrap tooltip" in bold font and rest in normal font. How can i achieve this?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704789/can-i-use-complex-html-with-twitter-bootstraps-tooltip

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you can see in  [Bootstrap' official documnetation for tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

```
Name    |    Type       |    default  |    Description
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
html    |    boolean    |    false    |    Insert html into the tooltip. 
                                           If false, jquery's text method 
                                           will be used to insert content 
                                           into the dom. Use text if you're 
                                           worried about XSS attacks.
```

so, add `data-html="true"` to your tooltip and this will enable HTML in your tooltip