# Bootstrap Tooltip with angular not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am using Tooltip Boostrap, but I could not make this working in my angular code, I tough angular code like: :{{o.client_name}}, :{{o.client_name}} will work in that code, but it's not working, someone know why?

Angular Code:

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="o in form.users" ng-show="form.users.length">
           <div>
                <p><b>title</b>:{{o.title}}</p>
                <p><b>client name</b>:{{o.client_name}}</p>
                <p><b>description</b>:{{o.description}}</p>
                <p><b>dev tool</b>:{{o.primary_develop}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="base_image_div">
            <img ng-src="/images/{{o.thumbnail}}" class="img-responsive base_image" alt="{{o.description}}">
          </div>

    </div>
```

My tooltip code with Angular:

```
<div class="container">  
    <a href="#" class="custom-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-html="true"  title="" 
    data-title="<div class='row ballon-tooltip'>
           <ul>
                      <li>  <b>title</b>:{{o.title}}</li>
                      <li>  <b>client name</b>:{{o.client_name}} </li>
                      <li>  <b>description</b>:{{o.description}}</li>
                      <li>  <b>dev tool</b>:{{o.primary_develop}}</li>
           </ul>
                </div>">
<img ng-src="../public/images/{{o.thumbnail}}" class="img-responsive base_image" alt="{{o.description}}"></a></li>

</div>
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
                });
                </script>
```

Comment: Are you really hoping to inject html like that as `data-title`?

Comment: I can see here it's possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704789/can-i-use-complex-html-with-twitter-bootstraps-tooltip

Answer (score 1):

In a bootstrap-only situation it works right away -> **http://jsfiddle.net/5h6kc5o5/**

I believe your problem is the use of `$(document).ready()` - it is useless in an angular context. It is executed long before angular has finished rendering. Use a `$timeout` instead :

```
$timeout(function() {
   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
})
```

Then `tooltip()` is called in the next loop.