# How to use mathjax inside qtip on a cytoscape node

Tags: javascript, mathjax, cytoscape.js, qtip2

How could I use the Mathjax library within qtip in a cytoscape node?

In the sample code below, the tooltip is displayed when clicking over the top of a node, but the Mathjax is not rendered.

How can this be fixed so that the equation is also shown in the tooltip? The solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398214/how-to-use-mathjax-inside-a-bootstrap-tooltip/40404772#40404772) by @peterkrautzberger could be an option, but I didn't manage to adapt it to this case.

**Edited:** The answer by @dipenshah solves the original question. However, when extending the sample code allowing for dynamic Mathjax content it doesn't seem to work. If instead of having a fixed text for the tooltips, the text is taken from the element `txt` in the definition of the node, then the Mathjax is not rendered. I have modified the code below to show it.

```js
$(function(){
    var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
        container: document.getElementById('cy'),

        ready: function(){
        },

        elements: {
            nodes: [
                { data: { id: '1', name: 'Node 1', txt: '$$\\int f(x)dx=\\frac{x^2+y}{2x} + C\\,.$$' }, },
                { data: { id: '2', name: 'Node 2', txt: '$$\\frac{\\partial x^2}{dx}\\,.$$' }, }
            ],
            edges: [
                { data: { source: '1', target: '2' } }
            ]
        }
    });

    cy.elements().nodes().qtip({
        content: function(){ return this.data('txt') },
        position: {
            my: 'top center',
            at: 'bottom center'
        },
        style: {
            classes: 'qtip-bootstrap',
            tip: {
                width: 16,
                height: 8
            }
        },
    events: {
      render: function() {
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
      }
    }
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape-qtip@2.7.1/cytoscape-qtip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
<h3>Cytoscape qtip demo</h3>

<p>
$$\int f(x)dx=\frac{x^2+y}{2x} + C\,.$$
</p>

<div id="cy" style="width:50%; height:50%; position:absolute;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Based on updated question:**
For dynamic content there is no guarantee that by the time MathJax starts processing dom element will be available in the same event callback, so here we can use `setTimeout` to queue processing after current Javascript calls have finished processing:

```
render: function(event, api) {
  var tooltip = api.elements.tooltip;
  tooltip.bind('tooltipshow', function(event, api) {
    setTimeout(() => MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]));
  });
}
```

Let's take a look:

```js
$(function() {
  var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),

    ready: function() {},

    elements: {
      nodes: [{
          data: {
            id: '1',
            name: 'Node 1',
            txt: '$$\\int f(x)dx=\\frac{x^2+y}{2x} + C\\,.$$'
          },
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: '2',
            name: 'Node 2',
            txt: '$$\\frac{\\partial x^2}{dx}\\,.$$'
          },
        }
      ],
      edges: [{
        data: {
          source: '1',
          target: '2'
        }
      }]
    }
  });

  cy.elements().nodes().qtip({
    content: function() {
      return this.data('txt');
    },
    position: {
      my: 'top center',
      at: 'bottom center'
    },
    style: {
      classes: 'qtip-bootstrap',
      tip: {
        width: 16,
        height: 8
      }
    },
    events: {
      render: function(event, api) {
        var tooltip = api.elements.tooltip;
        tooltip.bind('tooltipshow', function(event, api) {
          setTimeout(() => MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]));
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/3.0.3/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.css">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape-qtip@2.7.1/cytoscape-qtip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>

<h3>Cytoscape qtip demo</h3>

<p>
  $$\int f(x)dx=\frac{x^2+y}{2x} + C\,.$$
</p>

<div id="cy" style="width:50%; height:50%; position:absolute;"></div>
```

**Original answer:**

You can use `render` callback on `qtip`, to let `MathJax` know about update:

```
events: {
  render: function() {
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
  }
}
```

checkout updated code:

```js
$(function() {
  var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    elements: {
      nodes: [{
          data: {
            id: '1',
            name: 'Node 1'
          },
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: '2',
            name: 'Node 2'
          },
        }
      ],
      edges: [{
        data: {
          source: '1',
          target: '2'
        }
      }]
    }
  });

  var qtip = cy.elements().nodes().qtip({
    content: '$$\int f(x)dx=\frac{x^2+y}{2x} + C\,.$$',
    position: {
      my: 'top center',
      at: 'bottom center'
    },
    style: {
      classes: 'qtip-bootstrap',
      tip: {
        width: 16,
        height: 8
      }
    },
    events: {
      render: function() {
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/3.0.3/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.css">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape-qtip@2.7.1/cytoscape-qtip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>

<h3>Cytoscape qtip demo</h3>

<p>
  $$\int f(x)dx=\frac{x^2+y}{2x} + C\,.$$
</p>

<div id="cy" style="width:50%; height:50%; position:absolute;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the original question. When extending the original example, I came up with a related issue as explained in the paragraph added to the question. Solving this new issue will not be required to get the answer accepted, but I would appreciate any ideas to fix it.

Comment: @javlacalle did you take a look?