# <br> tag not working in table td data-title attribute

Tags: html

I want to add data-title attribute for responsive data-table. And `td` data-title contains break statement tag. But break statement tag is not working. Below is my sample code,

```
<td data-title='Goods<br>Code'></td>
```

I want both 'Goods' and 'Code' in two lines.

Comment: You cannot use HTML tags in `data-` attributes.

Answer (score 3):

I think `data-*` attributes only support string and html code will not effect on it so try to change

```
<td data-title='Goods<br>Code'></td>
```

to

```
<td data-title="Goods\nCode"></td>
```

\n as new line

EDIT

Try to add `data-html="true"`
I see this answer please check it
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13705417/5441049

Or use JQuery tooltip plugin

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tooltip.asp

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13705417/5441049 and try to add data-html="true"

Comment: i have added that too.But no response.I am building my table dynamically

Comment: Then use a jquery or bootstrap plugin for tooltip to meet your needs
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tooltip.asp

Answer (score 2):

This one should work :

```css
#table th, #table td{
    padding:0.8em;
    border: 1px solid;
}
#table th{
    background-color:#6699FF;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Text</th>
       
    </tr>
 <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td title="Goods&#010;Code">Hover Me</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Just run the snippet and hover over the "Hover Me" cell and you should see the title just as you desired it to be.

> ```
> "&#013; is \r and &#010; is \n
> On Windows new line is &#013;&#010; on unix &#010;"
> ```

Comment: i am using this data-title attribute to get responsive data-table.If i use just title, nothing is visible .

Comment: I'll come up with a solution for data-title attribute shortly

Comment: Has anyone come up with a solution to this yet?