# bootstrap js tooltip display html content

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am trying to display html content on tooltip title.

But the plain text is being displayed.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip1" title="<p><label>package_qty</label> (0 status)</p>">0</a>
```

And initialization:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip1"]').tooltip();
```

Setting `data-html` value to `true` seems to be not working.

I am using bootstrap version `3.3.7`.

Answer (score 1):

hopefully these links can help you, have a nice day!

discussion [Can I use complex HTML with Twitter Bootstrap's Tooltip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704789/can-i-use-complex-html-with-twitter-bootstraps-tooltip)

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/44khF/200/

```js
$('.tooltip-demo.well').tooltip({
  selector: "a[rel=tooltip]"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="tooltip-demo well">
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0;" class="muted">Tight pants next level keffiyeh you probably haven't heard of them. Photo booth beard raw denim letterpress vegan messenger bag stumptown. Farm-to-table seitan, mcsweeney's fixie sustainable quinoa 8-bit american apparel have a terry richardson vinyl chambray. Beard stumptown, cardigans banh mi lomo thundercats. Tofu biodiesel williamsburg marfa, four loko mcsweeney's cleanse vegan chambray. A <a title="<h1><b>Another</b> <em>one</em> here too</h1>" data-html="true" rel="tooltip" href="#">really ironic</a> artisan whatever keytar, scenester farm-to-table banksy Austin twitter handle freegan cred raw denim single-origin coffee viral.
</p></div>
```