# Styling bootstrap tooltip word in bold

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use tooltips with bootstrap. I have a sentence and want only one word in bold but it keeps showing up as plain text with tags.

I have used data-html ="true" but it doesn't change anything.

```
<p title="This is the sentence that I want to show with the <strong> tooltip </strong>" data-html="true">
                        Hover here
                    </p>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704789/can-i-use-complex-html-with-twitter-bootstraps-tooltip. Would this fix your issue ?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. styling keeps showing up as plain text

Comment: which is the version of bootstrap you are using ? i guess you need to add data-toggle="tooltip" for it to be considered as a tooltip so the data-html will work

Comment: I am using bootstrap v3. tried data-toggle="tooltip" and data-bs-toggle="tooltip". Nothing seems to be working

Comment: does the actual tooltip work ? the basic functionality ? if not, did you add jquery to your project ?

Comment: Whenever I hover, the tooltip works, but if I have any styling tags, they are being rendered as plain text even though I am using data-html="true"

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/vj0du5ko/1/

Comment: Does the bootstrap tooltip work  ? or it just shows the default title 'tooltip ' ? I guess it just shows the default html 'title tooltip' which is not the tooltip you want. Please add jquery to your project ( as it's a bs3 dependency when using tooltips ) and add the tooltip method to your element `$("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip();`

Answer (score 0):

call this function

```
<p title="This is the sentence that I want to show with the <strong> tooltip </strong>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true">Hover here</p>

$("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/vj0du5ko/2/

Answer (score 0):

tooltip " data-toggle="tooltip"data-html="true"> Hover here
$(document).ready(function(){$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   });

Answer (score -2):

tooltip " data-toggle="tooltip"data-html="true">Hover here

Comment: You have to activate tooltip but you haven’t activated yet so that’s reason that is why it is not working