# How to show array in a td inside the while

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have the following code:

```
$result7 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql7);
$resalm = mysqli_query($conn, $contalm);

$p = array();
while($row_alm = mysqli_fetch_array($resalm)) {
  $p[] = $row_alm['nome'];
}

while($rows_cursos7 = mysqli_fetch_array($result7)) {
  $tabela8 .= '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title='.$p.'>'.$rows_cursos7['Almoço'].'</button></td>';
}
```

The problem is that if you do it inside the while `print_r($p)` it returns the data coming from the database.

But inside the button `title='.$p.'` it only returns array and not the data that comes from the database. Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show all the items from `$p` inside the second loop, you'll also need to loop that array, or at least `implode` it (depending on the exact nature of the output you want to see).

For example:

Using [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
while($rows_cursos7 = mysqli_fetch_array($result7)) {
  $tabela8 .= '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="'.implode(", ", $p).'">'.$rows_cursos7['Almoço'].'</button></td>';
}
```

Using a loop:

```
while($rows_cursos7 = mysqli_fetch_array($result7)) {
  $tabela8 .= '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="';

  foreach ($p as $i)
  {
    $tabela8 .= $i." - ";
  }

  $tabela8 .= '">'.$rows_cursos7['Almoço'].'</button></td>';
}
```

N.B. It's unclear if this is the output you actually want, as that wasn't clear from the question, but it shows you a couple of ways you can access the individual array elements, which you can then adapt to get the output you are really trying to achieve.

Comment: One more thing, in the implode when separated by a comma is it possible to make a paragraph?

Comment: You can put anything you want as the separator

Comment: To make the paragraph I put it like this, `"'.implode(",/n ", $p).'"`, but it didn't work

Comment: Well a newline in plain-text is `\n` not `/n`, for a start. And also you're doing it in a HTML attribute whose purpose is not known to me. I've no idea whether the context in which you end up seeing that data will recognise plain-text newline characters or not. If it ends up being displayed in a HTML context, `<br>` is the HTML newline tag (and that's assuming the intervening code doesn't strip or encode HTML tags in the source data).

Comment: It doesn't work, I already tried: `"'.implode(",\n ", $p).'"`, `"'.implode(",<br>, $p). '"`, `"'.implode(",</br> ", $p).'"`, `"'.implode(",<p></p> ", $p).'"`. None resulted

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap's tooltips? If so then, as I suspected, it doesn't allow HTML content by default. Did you check the documentation? Look at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/#options and find the `html` option. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704789/can-i-use-complex-html-with-twitter-bootstraps-tooltip for more info